# SELECT DISTINCT on one column in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In `SQL Sever 2014`, I have a table like this:

```
tag_id        prd_id        prod_nm
--------------------------------------
1               1           apple
2               1           apple
3               1           apple
4               2           banana
5               2           banana
6               3           tomato
7               3           tomato
8               4           cabbage
9               5           melon
```

And I want to get the highest `tag_id` for each product.

```
tag_id   prd_id     prod_nm
------------------------------
3       1           apple
5       2           banana
7       3           tomato
8       4           cabbage
9       5           melon
```

I used `Distinct`, `Top`, `Order by` but it isn't working. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `max()` aggregate function but then you have to do a `group by` to group the result-set by the other columns:

```
SELECT max(tag_id) AS tag_id, prd_id, prod_nm 
FROM table 
GROUP BY prd_id, prod_nm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max` with `group by`

```
select max(tag_id)tag_id,prd_id,prod_nm 
from mytable 
group by prd_id,prod_nm
```